# Configuring telnet on my new Ubuntu VM

Tags: telnet

I want to configure telnet for my fresh Ubuntu VM.
Can you please provide the necessary steps?

I'm also looking for steps to configure ssh in a Ubuntu system and how it can be connected from a client using ssh.

Answer (score 4):

If you're asking for the telnet client, it should be installed already. Try typing `telnet` in a terminal. If not, `sudo apt install telnet` will install it.

You do **not** want telnet server. There's zero reasons to use telnet in 2018. It's unsecure and offers no benefits.

To set up SSH, simply

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
sudo systemctl enable sshd
sudo systemctl start sshd
```

If you have firewall configured, you can allow ssh with `sudo ufw allow ssh`.

To configure key based login, [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/822906/how-to-login-to-vps-using-ssh-rsa-keys) may help.